# Cant add a class to a img tag

Tags: javascript, class, owl-carousel

i have 3 slides in a image carrousel and a i want to add the class animated and bounceInDown to the 3 img tags with Ids melon-fruta , frutilla-fruta and banana-fruta, when i log the the element in the console it seems to work fine but in the elements tab in developers tools the attributes doesnt show in the img tags.

```
var owl = $('.carrousel .owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel();
        // Listen to owl events:
    owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function (event) {
        var page = event.page.index;
        if(page == 0){
            console.log(page);
            const element = document.getElementById("melon-fruta");
            element.classList.add('animated', 'bounceInDown','delay-1s');
            console.log(element);
        }else if(page == 1){
            const element = document.getElementById("frutilla-fruta");
            element.classList.add('animated', 'bounceInDown','delay-1s');
            console.log(element);
        }else if(page == 2){
            const element = document.getElementById("banana-fruta");
            element.classList.add('animated', 'bounceInDown','delay-1s');
            console.log(element);
        }

    });
```

Comment: If they're showing up when you log the element in the console, why do you think it's not working?

Comment: is showing in the console but not in the img tag , only when page == 0 the element has the classes.

Comment: Maybe something else is removing the classes by the time you look in the elements tab.